# Upload set of POJOs, JsonMappingException Already had POJO for id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-rest

I try to upload a set of POJOs (Snp) which have a Many-To-One, One-To-Many bi-directional relationship with another POJO (User).
But when I try to upload the set of POJOs (from my client to a spring boot rest api) with the following body in the request:

> Request Body: [{"id":0,"snp":"AMg=","owner":null},{"id":0,"snp":"ASw=","owner":null},{"id":0,"snp":"Alg=","owner":null},{"id":0,"snp":"AZA=","owner":null},{"id":0,"snp":"ZA==","owner":null},{"id":0,"snp":"AfQ=","owner":null}]

I get the following error:

> Response Body: {"timestamp":1488451488989,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=0, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=org.barj.shindan.biology.Snp]] (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[1]->org.barj.shindan.biology.Snp[\"id\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=0, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=org.barj.shindan.biology.Snp]] (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[1]->org.barj.shindan.biology.Snp[\"id\"])","path":"/api/user/me/snps"}

---

### My User Pojo:

```java
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = User.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.auto)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Snp> snps = new HashSet<>();

    protected User() {}

    public void addSnp(Snp snp) {
        this.snps.add(snp);
        snp.setOwner(this);
    }

    public long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
      return username;
    }

    public Set<Snp> getSnps() {
      return snps;
    }

    public void setSnps(Set<Snp> snps) {
      for (Snp snp : snps) {
          addSnp(snp);
      }
    }
}
```

### My Snp Pojo:

```java
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Snp.class)
public class Snp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.auto)
    private long id;

    @column(name = "snp", columnDefinition = "blob", nullable = false)
    private byte[] snp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    protected Snp() {}

    public long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public byte[] getSnp() {
      return snp;
    }

    public User getOwner() {
      return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User user) {
      owner = user;
    }
}
```

---

My question is, how do I upload a collection of POJOs without having to specify an (unique) id. I wish for `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to take care of that. Applying `@JsonIgnore` to the id field does not work.

Comment: Could use a separate request pojo. Wondering if there's a work around.